# jQuery line not working inside callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [QueryLoader2](http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/queryloader2-preload-your-images-with-ease/) and I want the `fadeInUp` class to be removed from `#projects-list` and `footer p` but it's not doing it for some reason. I want the classes to be removed right after the callback function for `slideDown()`. Did I format it incorrectly?

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    new QueryLoader2(document.querySelector("body"), {
        barColor: "#fff",
        backgroundColor: "#000",
        percentage: true,
        barHeight: 1,
        minimumTime: 200,
        fadeOutTime: 0,
        onComplete: function() {
            $('#masthead').slideDown(100, function(){
                $('#projects-list, footer p').show().addClass('fadeInUp');
            });
            $('#projects-list, footer p').removeClass('fadeInUp');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Based on this code, you are removing the class then adding it 100ms later.  Either put some delay, such as setTimeout around the remove class or include it inside the slideDown complete.

Comment: @rfornal Thanks the `setTimeout` worked.

Comment: I'm going to post this so that you can mark a correct answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code above, you are removing the class then adding it 100ms later. This makes it look like the `fadeInUp` class is not removed.

Either:

1. Put some delay into the process of removal, such as `setTimeout` around the remove class, or
2. Include it inside the `slideDown` complete function.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but try something like this:

```
       onComplete: function() {
            $('#masthead').slideDown(100, function(){
                 //this is very you should have your code that you want to execute after 
                 // slide down
                  $('#projects-list, footer p').removeClass('fadeInUp');
                 // do you need the line below?
                //$('#projects-list, footer p').show().addClass('fadeInUp');

            });

        }
```